# linux du command in shell function only produces one line of output

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have been using `du` command to show file usage:

```bsh
$ sudo du -hsx /* | sort -rh | head -n 40
16G     /home
5.3G    /var
2.6G    /usr
840M    /run
...
```

And I want to write a function to save me from repetitive work:

```bsh
show_disk() {
    sudo du -hsx "$1" | sort -rh | head -n 40
}
```

But when I run this funciton, `du` only gets one line of output shown like:

```bsh
$ show_disk() /*
0   /bin
```

It seems to me that `du` command behaves differently in a shell function, where did I go wrong with this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `show_disk /*` expands to `show_disk /bin /etc /...`. $1 is therefore /bin. You want to replace $1 with $@ or $*.

Comment: @berndbausch thanks, `sudo du -hsx $* | sort -rh | head -n 40` did the trick for me.

Comment: @oeter Use `"$@"` (including the double-quotes) instead of `$*` to avoid parsing weirdness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$1` is the first argument. Remember that it's the shell that expands wildcards not the app, so `*` is not a single argument unless it matches only one (or no) file/directory.

You should use double-quoted `"$@"` in your script if you want to accept all the arguments. (Don't use `$*` as it will break with filenames containing spaces.)